# How to group based on rows and remove duplicates from each group

Tags: excel

I have an excel table with three columns -- Version, ID, Date -- below is an example of my table. What I am trying to do is group by the Version column and eliminate all duplicate IDs within that group. For example, I would like to only have AB124 appear once under version=1, but not to eliminate the duplicate AB124 in the version=3 group.

| Version | ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AB123 | 2021-01-04 |
| 1 | AB124 | 2019-05-06 |
| 1 | AB124 | 2019-05-06 |
| 2 | AB123 | 2021-01-04 |
| 3 | AB124 | 2019-05-15 |
| 3 | AB125 | 2021-05-05 |
| 3 | AB125 | 2021-05-06 |

If anyone has any advice, please let me know. I have been banging my head against this problem all day.

Thanks :)

Comment: Sort and remove duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

There is a button in excel that lets you do this actually. You can find it under the Data Tab > Remove duplicates and then select the fields you want to group by.

[Here is a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw2sv.png)